# Generating a contour plot based on a matrix of z values using MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a dictionary of lists:

```
dict = {}
for x in range(0, 11):
    dict[x] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How would I go about creating a contour plot from this data? The data structure is basically a matrix of z values, where the x and y coordinates are equivalent to the dictionary key and value respectively.

Comment: Convert your data into a numpy array would be a good first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your datatype correctly, to convert it into a numpy array and then plot it, you could do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# The example dict/matrix
dict = {}
for x in range(0, 11):
    dict[x] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# Create an empty numpy array with the right dimensions
nparr = np.zeros((len(dict.keys()), len(dict[0])))

# Loop through converting each list into a row of the new array
for ii in xrange(nparr.shape[0]):
    nparr[ii] = dict[ii]

# Plotting as a contour
plt.contour(nparr)
plt.show()
```

Note that the for loop won't be particularly quick for very large datasets, but should be fine for "image sized" data (I'd expect matplotlib's rendering to take the most time at any rate).